# Cant remove brackets on underside of bathroom sink

Tags: faucet, sink, bathroom-fixtures, brackets

I can’t figure out how to remove (or even turn) these brackets.  Has anyone seen them or know how to work with these?  I’ve done a lot of searching and can’t find anything.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Do you know the make and model of the faucet?

Comment: Think it might be a spring type holder.  Need to see if you can push/pull it up or down.  Are they two different places?  Both pictures do not look like at same place.

Comment: @isherwood - Yes the faucet.  These brackets are in 3 places: under faucet and hot and cold water knobs.

Comment: @Alaska Man - No, it was installed in 2004 though.

Comment: @crip659 - It does not move, it is tight against the ceramic in the bottom pic, which is a water knob.  That is the same spot you can see at the bottom edge of the top pic. It's a very tight space and hard for me to even get my hand up in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases I see a U shaped metal foot that attached to the fitting by two spurs that pass through hole in it,

This is probably tigtened (and loosened) from above.
however if you spread the arms of the U apart it will let go.

Comment: Actually, the ones under the water controls came right off (the bottom pic).  The top pic is the faucet and that is not moving at all.  I can see threads on the tube that controls the water stopper for the sink, but I'm not sure how to loosen the faucet head now.  There are no screws on the faucet or anything there I can see to loosen.  Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't see anyway to release it from below except spreading those arms apart.

Comment: A lot more force was required for that one, but it came off as well.  Thanks again!